# Facebook getLoginStatus return function not firing when page refresh

Tags: facebook, facebook-authentication

I'm using Facebook Javascript SDK.  For my app, I can have a user either login using Facebook, Twitter, or an account (email/password).  I can get Facebook authentication to work.  After successful Facebook authentication, I create a user session and the user proceeds to use the app.  I have a logout button in the app that destroys the session and sends user back to the login page.

When the user lands back on login page, they are still connected to Facebook.  I've tried calling FB.logout but the return function for getLoginStatus never fires.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{ 
    FB.init({appId: 99999999, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true}); 

    //LOGOUT FB USER
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
    {
        alert("status: " + response.status);
        if (response.authResponse) 
        {
            FB.logout();
            alert('logged out');
        }

    }, true);   

    //SUBSCRIBE TO LOGIN EVENT
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) 
    {
        if(response.authResponse) 
        {
            FB.api('/me', function(response) 
            {
                             //at this point user has been authenticated so they can continue with app...
            });                 
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Ooops, the Facebook authentication has failed.  Please try again.");
        }
    });
};

(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; 
    if (d.getElementById(id)){ return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(js);
    }(document));
```

What are the best practices around incorporating Facebook authentication into your app?  How do you manage logging user out of your app without logging them out of facebook altogether?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

The FB SDKs only supports logging out from FB, and then you can use the callback for logging the user out from your own site.
In this case you want to logout the user from your own site but not FB - then you should not use the SDK for logout, as this is used to logout the user from FB.

Instead you will have to make some kind of "reverted" login system.

1. If the user logs in with FB then set a session/cookie "mySiteLogin".
2. When checking for authorization, check both the FB-login AND "mySiteLogin".
3. When the user clicks logout unset/delete "mySiteLogin".

This is just a solution of the top of my head. But I too was not able to find any out-of-the-box solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's three things that are all trying to do something with login

- `status: true`
- `FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)`
- `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login'`

When status is set to true, the SDK will call facebook to see if the current user is authenticated. Then you also have a check again of `getLoginStatus` and then while that is running async, you subscribe to the `auth.login`.

`auth.login` will be called even from the `status: true` call and possibly again from the getLoginStatus call.

Instead of doing `alert`s which interrupt the flow, do `console.log`s so you can see what's being called when.

As for this question: "I do not want to log them out of facebook from my app. Is this even possible?"

Yes, you can log the user out of your app by sending an HTTP DELETE to `me/permissions` with that user's valid access token.  This will force them to reauth your app the next time.  It's about the only effective way I know of to get them "out of my app" but not log them out of their facebook session.